# Is there a case-insensitive version of the `:/<text>` tree-ish?

Tags: git

Let's say I have git commit message `Hello World`.

`:/"World"` will find it, `:/"world"` will not.

Any way to make git match case-insensitively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does not seem supported by the [`:/<text>` syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emlttextgtemegemfixnastybugem).
This would work, as a workaround:

```
git log :/[Ww]orld
```

Or, using the [`-i/--regexp-ignore-case`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--i):

```
git log -i --grep "world"
```